# "Follow Link" doesn't work with Absolute Paths in Visual Studio Code Terminal ("Unable to open <file>")

Tags: linux, visual-studio, vscode-code-runner

I'm new to VS code, and it's maybe something simple.

I'm using **Visual Studio Code** (version 1.77.1) on my **Linux Mint** workstation to work with a **Javascript / Typescript** project.

I'm using the **Code Runner Extension** to run js files. Whenever a path is shown in **Code Terminal**, control clicking on it doesn't work and shows this message:

[image]

```
Unable to open '<file>'
The editor could not be opened because the file was not found"
```

The path is correctly **prefixed with `file://`, it's absolute, and it exists**, so it should have no problems:

[image]

Thanks a lot in advance, please let me know if you need any additional detail.